# errors.Is(err, target error) returns false when the two errors have the same string

Tags: go

[image: VSCode outpute]

This shouldn't fail because the two errors have the same string, but it still fails:

```
    if !errors.Is(err, testspec.expectErr) {
        t.Errorf("Error mismatch, want %v, get %v", testspec.expectErr, err)
    }
```

This is the errors Is() function called:

```
func Is(err, target error) bool {
    if target == nil {
        return err == target
    }

    isComparable := reflectlite.TypeOf(target).Comparable()
    for {
        if isComparable && err == target {
            return true
        }
        if x, ok := err.(interface{ Is(error) bool }); ok && x.Is(target) {
            return true
        }
        // TODO: consider supporting target.Is(err). This would allow
        // user-definable predicates, but also may allow for coping with sloppy
        // APIs, thereby making it easier to get away with them.
        if err = Unwrap(err); err == nil {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`errors.Is` does not check that the error strings are the same. Assuming the errors have been creating using `errors.New`, this is documented behavior:

From https://pkg.go.dev/errors#New

> ```
> func New(text string) error
> ```
>
> New returns an error that formats as the
> given text. Each call to New returns a distinct error value even if the text is identical.

From the additional code you've added to the question, it looks like you think that the two `&errorString{"block #11 not found"}` values should compare equal. But these are two pointers, and (from the language reference under "comparison operators"):

> Pointer values are comparable. **Two pointer values are equal if they
> point to the same variable or if both have value nil.** Pointers to
> distinct zero-size variables may or may not be equal.

Comment: Therefore, how does that work with unit tests? I will need to call New for both the expected and observed... Am I back to reflect.DeepEqual?

Comment: If you want to check the strings, you can use `err.Error()` to get the string. For example: `strings.Contains(err.Error(), "block #11")`

Comment: Right, or else I would need to set a var with the errors.New then assigned it to the expected at setup time and then to the observed when I run the test and it passes. Is that right?

Comment: Or you could design your error values, for example, using a custom error type.

Comment: There's many choices, but if the information in the error is important and you want to unit-test it (rather than for example checking nil or not-nil), then making a custom error type with the important information in it is a good approach. Doing some sort of string match is a quick-and-dirty approach that's also ok if the specifics of your error strings are not (considered at the moment by you) part of your api.

Comment: I think it's okay to go with strings in that case as the error message provides the precise reason why the test fails (block number). I am a bit disappointed that two NewError would be tested as different if their string (the only field in the struct) are equal. Any reason for this added opinionated complexity?

Comment: @JohnDifool I don't think it's obviously more or less complex or opinionated if two independently created errors are the same or different if they have the same error string. You obviously see one of the choices as better than the other. The go authors made the other choice and documented it, and that's how it is.